# Are cohomology functors sheaves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, cohomology, sheaf-theory

Question is the following:

> Is the functor $H^n_{dR}:\text{Man}\rightarrow \text{Set}$ a sheaf with respect to open cover topology on $\text{Man}$?

More generally, are cohomology functors sheaves in general (in any reasonably non trivial Grothendieck topology)?

I am also interested in cohomology functors that arise in Algebriac geometry/topology.

Is there a way of sheafification in this setup?

I have nothing much to support this question, this is completely out of curiosity.

Edit : I am also interested in answers/references related to the comment of  Piotr Achinger; that reads

> "in what way is cohomology a sheaf" leads one to notions like $\infty$-topoi etc.

Comment: No, in fact the cohomology presheaves $U\mapsto H^n_{\rm dR}(U)$ sheafify to zero for $n>0$.

Comment: No, as almost any example demonstrates (a sphere, for instance, covered by two contractible open sets); if cohomology were a sheaf the Mayer-Vietoris sequence would split as short exact sequences of $H^k$ for each $k$. $C^*(M)$ forms a sheaf of complexes, but the gluing property does not survive passing to cohomology.

Comment: Oh, no. I did not think about that @MikeMiller. That is straight forward that it is not expected to be sheaf.. this is a stupid question. I should not have asked it here (not in this form)  :D

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Ok. It is not immediate for me, I will think about it. Thanks :)

Comment: The question is not stupid - trying to make sense of "in what way is cohomology a sheaf" leads one to notions like $\infty$-topoi etc.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger that is interesting. can you please suggest some (possibly short) reference that introduce $\infty$-topoi when trying to understand in what sense cohomology is a sheaf?

Comment: This upvote downvote game is funny :D 3 upvotes, 2 downvotes.

Comment: I don't know a particularly good introduction because, like many of the core concepts that motivate infinity categories,  this idea is folklore which only (relatively) recently accquired a more precise accepted meaning.  But the point is that there is an infinity category of chain complexes $Ch$, and the functor $U \mapsto C^*(U)$ becomes a sheaf in the infinity categorical sense.  (In turn $\infty$-categories of sheaves of spaces (instead of chain complexes)  are the paradigmatic example of $\infty$-topoi).

Comment: @PhilTosteson Ok. I am afraid I might lost the path if I google for infinity topoi and look for relation with Piotr Achinger's comment. Can you suggest some starting point towards this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the functor H^n_dR:Man→Set a sheaf with respect to open cover topology on Man?

As already pointed out in the comments, the answer is no for n>0, yes for n=0.

> "in what way is cohomology a sheaf" leads one to notions like ∞-topoi etc.

In the context of this question,
the assignment M↦Ω(M) yields a contravariant
functor from smooth manifolds to cochain complexes,
and this functor satisfies the homotopy descent condition.

This was first proved by Weil in Sur les théorèmes de de Rham ([DigiZeitschriften](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/download/PPN358147735_0026/PPN358147735_0026___log13.pdf), [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/bf02564296), [EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/139040)).
An accessible exposition is given by Bott and Tu in §8 of [Differential Forms in
Algebraic Topology](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=F8BA716DD25F37E6D3085BCB201D08E3).

Comment: The link http://www.springerlink.com/index/10.1007/BF02564296 is broken..

Comment: I will read the part you mentioned from Bott and Tu. I am hearing the word “homotopic descent condition” for the first time. I can guess what it is, but I will read about it and ask if I have any further questions..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Try https://eudml.org/doc/139040 for Weil's paper, though EuDML is down for maintenance at the moment. Here's an unofficial link: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/weil.pdf

Comment: @DavidRoberts ok

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I have no links to SpringerLink in my post.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: The homotopy (not homotopic) descent condition is also known as the ∞-sheaf condition, and it is also used to define stacks in groupoids as presheaves of groupoids that satisfy the homotopy descent condition.

Comment: Previously you have mentioned http://www.springerlink.com/index/10.1007/BF02564296 as link for Weil’s paper, that is what I was mentioning. Yes, I misread homotopy as homotopic.. Thanks for the edit..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik you should compare the actual URL Dmitri posted (eg by looking at the mouseover url, copying the link, looking at the answer source markdown etc) compared to where it lands after redirection. That said, both EuDML and Sprinklink are both still not working for me, so I hope the ahem other link is useful.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: There is also a perfectly official version from DigiZeitschriften that I just added.  Theoretically, DOI entries should be updated with new URLs, but I guess this does not always happen in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the edit